# Mysql calculation result in where clause?

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a vBulletin forum. The idea is to create a webpage where admins can query all the latest posts and "read" them so they get marked as "checked".

The webpage works perfectly fine, however, the query is a bit slow because we get thousends of new posts every single day and right now it's pulling all posts from the past 24 hours.

To solve the issue, I want it to only pull the posts that aren't checked yet.

The original query is as follows:

```
SELECT 
thread.forumid, thread.firstpostid, thread.lastpost, thread.lastposter, thread.lastpostid, thread.replycount, 
thread.threadid, thread.title, thread.open, thread.views, post.pagetext AS preview, post.userid AS lastpuserid, threadread.readtime AS readtime, threadread.userid AS userid
FROM thread AS thread
LEFT JOIN deletionlog AS deletionlog ON (thread.threadid = deletionlog.primaryid AND deletionlog.type = 'thread')
LEFT JOIN post AS post ON (post.postid = thread.lastpostid)
LEFT JOIN threadread AS threadread ON (threadread.threadid = thread.threadid AND threadread.userid = 90122)
WHERE open <> 10
AND thread.lastpost >=  1494100000
AND thread.forumid NOT IN(0013482730313233343537)
AND thread.visible = '1'
AND post.visible = 1
AND deletionlog.primaryid IS NULL

GROUP BY thread.threadid
ORDER BY thread.lastpost DESC
```

To only get the unchecked posts, I need to calculate

`thread.lastpost-threadread.readtime > 0`

My first solution was to just add

`AND thread.lastpost-threadread.readtime > 0` to the where clause. However, this caused

`LEFT JOIN threadread AS threadread ON (threadread.threadid = thread.threadid AND threadread.userid = 90122)`

to only select the `threadread.userid = 90122` and not `threadread.threadid = thread.threadid`

So my idea was to do

`SELECT ... thread.lastpost-threadread.readtime AS isread`

and then `AND isread > 0`. This returned the error

> Unknown column 'isread'

I'm most likely trying to do something very stupid or simply don't understand how this entiry query is working, but I'm out of ideas on how to solve my problem. So now I'm asking you guys :)

Comment: Some sample data would be nice.  I couldn't follow your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Here's the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7dd95

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use table aliases, then shorten the names so the query is easier to write and to read.

Then, you need to fix the `JOIN`s.  The `WHERE` clause is turning some outer joins to inner joins.  Then, move the condition to the appropriate `ON` clause.

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT t.forumid, t.firstpostid, t.lastpost, t.lastposter, t.lastpostid, t.replycount, 
       t.threadid, t.title, t.open, t.views, p.pagetext AS preview, p.userid AS lastpuserid, tr.readtime AS readtime, tr.userid AS userid
FROM thread t JOIN
     post p
     ON p.postid = t.lastpostid LEFT JOIN
     deletionlog dl
     ON t.threadid = dl.primaryid AND dl.type = 'thread' LEFT JOIN
     threadread tr
     ON tr.threadid = t.threadid AND tr.userid = 90122 AND
        t.lastpost > tr.readtime
WHERE open <> 10 AND
      t.lastpost >=  1494100000 AND
      t.forumid NOT IN (0013482730313233343537) AND
      t.visible = 1 AND
      p.visible = 1 AND
      dl.primaryid IS NULL
GROUP BY t.threadid
ORDER BY t.lastpost DESC;
```

I'm not sure what the `GROUP BY` is supposed to be doing.  Using `GROUP BY` with no aggregation functions on the unaggregated columns is usually a really bad idea.  In this case, `t.threadid` is probably the primary key for the table, so the other columns from that table are fine.  But what if there are duplicates generated by joins to other tables?

Comment: And what would be the cause of the anonymous downvote?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your problem is that the `WHERE` condition turns the outer join to an inner join, which is why I suggest putting the condition in the `ON` clause.

Comment: Do you mind editing your answer with an example to that? I did not write the query myself and though I understand most of it, my knowledge falls short on joins. I understand how they work but I have no idea how I would put on `ON` clause on the condition

Comment: @icecub . . . It is in the answer.  I changed the condition to `t.lastpost > tr.readtime` because that seems much clearer.

Comment: I've been testing it but I'm afraid it's returning everything now. Including the ones that are already checked. I've tried adding `t.lastpost-tr.readtime AS isread` to see what they would return and though some were correctly > 0, most were just NULL

Comment: @icecub . . . It should not be returning more rows than without the condition.

Comment: No it's returning exactly the same as without the condition. It's as if it just ignores it.

Comment: I've made a short Pastebin for you where the important part of the original code is. Perhaps it helps you to understand what's going on :) https://pastebin.com/3tgEebFz

Comment: So basicly I'm trying to eliminate the query in the `while()` loop completely and just do it all with 1 query at the top and simply just select the ones that arent checked

Comment: Ah well. I'll focus on this tomorrow. +1 for giving great and advise and trying to help me out (and to get rid of that unfair downvote). Thanks :)

Comment: Well, the answer ends with a question, which would suggest that Gordon should probably have done a bit more digging in the form of comments before answering. So, a downvote may be a bit harsh, but definitely not unfair. That's the risk we run if we answer a question that's not clear.